# Gamma tail bound

Tags: probability

Earlier, someone asked me why, if $X\sim Gamma(r,\lambda)$, then $P(X\geq 2E(X))\leq (2/e)^r$.

I was able to show that $P(X < 2E(X))$ were bounded below by $$\frac{ 2r (r-1)^{r-1} e^{-(r-1)}}{\Gamma(r)}, $$ but $1$ minus this does not give me $(2/e)^r$. Does anyone know how to show the $(2/e)^r$ bound? Maybe it's simpler than what I'm expecting...

Comment: Ok I figured it out I think. It's a Chernoff bound. Someone else feel free to post the solution here. Otherwise, I'll close this question.